# Error: Can't combine `..1$A` <double> and `..2$A` <factor<ee569>>

Tags: r

I would like to use `bind_rows()` to append two dataframes (by their column headers) but when I run the code I get the Error: Can't combine `..1$A`  and `..2$A` <factor>.

I know I need to convert the *factor* to *double* but I don't know how to perform this operation on all columns.

I have approx 500 columns and thus cannot use `as.double`

One dataframe X is very large (500 columns and 5000 rows) and the other Y rather small (495 columns and only 1 row). The append should be done based on common column header. Basically I want to add the row of Y at the end of X.

Let me know if you need more information.

Thx

Comment: There are some good references for how to make a question more *reproducible* so that we can "play with" the code and data that you have, instead of trying to infer it. Please see https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269, [mcve], and https://stackoverflow.com/tags/r/info. One notable thing is that copying what a `data.frame` *looks like* on the console might seem useful, but with your mention of `factor`, that fails, since the representation of factors in a frame is nothing like how the internal data is stored. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**TLDR** force everything to be a factor.

I was able to reproduce your error by running this:

```
df1 <- data.frame (A = factor("Retail"), 
                   AA = factor("Automotive"), 
                   PR = factor("Automotive"), 
                   DFI = factor("Tech" )) 
df2 <- data.frame(A = 1, AA = 2, PR = 3, DFI = 4)

bind_rows(df1, df2)
```

Which gives me:

```
Error: Can't combine `..1$A` <character> and `..2$A` <double>.
```

I fix it by doing:

```
df2 <- mutate(df2, across(everything(), as.factor))
bind_rows(df1, df2)
```

And that works.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `across` to convert all the columns at once. Here's an example:

```
library(tidyverse)

# Here I'm just making an example dataframe with 26 columns
dat <- data.frame(letters = letters, n = factor(seq(26))) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = "letters", values_from = n)

# If you wanted to change all columns you'd just do:
dat %>% 
  mutate(across(cols_to_change, as.double))
```

And if you wanted to change a subset of columns (here I do 1-25 as an example), you'd do:

```
cols_to_change <- colnames(dat)[1:25]

# Use mutate_at to convert all at once
dat %>% 
  mutate(across(cols_to_change, as.double))
```